# Number(undefined) js is NaN

Tags: javascript

So in JS almost all falsey values return 0 when being used as the arguments for the Number function so Number(false), Number(null), Number(''), Number([]) all return 0.

My question is why does Number(undefined) return NaN?

Comment: If an argument cannot be converted to number, it will return `NaN`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: More Info: [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)

Comment: ok i get that but why can it convert all of the above and not undefined

Comment: Because everything other that `undefined` is a defined value

Answer (score 8):

because ECMA spec:

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3

I know, not a very satisfying answer

Comment: But it's still correct. Plus one.

Comment: A more precise path: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3

Comment: @Rajesh thank you, updated

Answer (score 1):

The question is: why `null` value should return `0`?
I think the reason of this behavior should be searched in what happen when I do operations with numbers and other values?

Let's try follow:

```js
//Normal operation
console.log(10 + 2);
//Number(false)
console.log(10 + false);
//Number(null)
console.log(10 + null);
//Number('')
console.log(10 + '');
//Number([])
console.log(10 + []);
//Number(undefined)
console.log(10 + undefined);

//All right operators returns 0 but undefined takes down the operation
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: When you do operation, it internally calls `toNumber` function which is also used in `Number()` so this answer will not help.

Answer (score 0):

The job of the `Number` function is to convert its argument into a number.

But NaN (not a number) is a curiosity in that it ought to be propagated by any numerical function.

`Number` conforms to this.